# Why events behave differently in this case?

Tags: c#, events, delegates, ienumerable

The following program

```
static IEnumerable<Action> Create()
{
    foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 2))
    {
        yield return () => { Console.Write(i); };
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (var func in Create())
    {
        func();
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

ouputs

> 01

And this program

```
static event Action SomethingHappened;

static void Register()
{
    foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 2))
    {
        SomethingHappened += () => { Console.Write(i); };
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Register();
    SomethingHappened();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

outputs

> 11

Why is that so? How to make the program 2 output `01`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're capturing the loop variable in your lambda expression. That means when the delegate is finally invoked, it will use the latest value of the variable... which will always be 1. Try this:

```
foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 2))
{
    int copy = i;
    SomethingHappened += () => { Console.Write(copy); };
}
```

... then read [Eric Lippert's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) about it.

Answer (score 1):

In the second program the variable `i` is captured by the lambda. To get the correct behavior make a local copy before using it in the lambda. E.g.

```
foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 2))
{
    var local = i;
    SomethingHappened += () => { Console.Write(local); };
}
```